# How do you do server discovery in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, networking, network-programming, client-server

We are apparently working on a ticket system (waiting game), and apparently, there needs to be a server discovery on the client module (3 modules: client, clerk, server). Please help, thank you!

========================================================================

more details on the task: The aim of this system is to create a network-based Queuing/Ticketing System, similar to that of a customer service counter or that of the Office of the Registrar’s Helpdesk.

The system consists of 3 modules, Server Module, Client Application Module and the Clerk Application Module.

The Client Application Module will be used to issue the “tickets” to the server. Upon startup, the Client Application Module should look for the server without requiring the user to input anything.

Once found, the Client Application Module has to determine the last issued ticket number from the server and continue issuing tickets from the last number.

The Server module will hold all the records of the tickets and their status. These records include who was the “client” and the “clerk” that handle the problem. The status of the tickets can be “Waiting” or “Accomplished”. By default, all tickets have the status of “Waiting”. Only the Clerk Application Module can change the status of a ticket to “Accomplished”.

The Clerk Application Module will be used to “accommodate” the tickets from the server. A “clerk” user, will be able to use the application to mark the tickets from a “Waiting” status to “Accomplished” status.

Upon startup of the Clerk Application Module, no input will be asked from the user except for the clerk’s name.

================================================================================

Apparently this is all we have so far:

client1.php just asks for the name

client2.php

```
            <!--

            client2.php - Adds client name into the database.

            -->

            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Waiting Game - Client</title>
                </head>

                <body>

                    <?php

                        // Create connection to database "comnets"
                        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                        mysql_select_db('comnets');

                        // Check connection
                            /*if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
                            {
                                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                            }else{ 
                                echo "Successfuly connected to the database.<br><br>";
                            }

                            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                            {
                                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                            }*/
                        // End connection

                        // Insert client name into the database
                        $client = "INSERT INTO client
                                   VALUES('','" . $_POST['clientname'] . "')";

                        $clientInserted = mysql_query($client) or die ( mysql_error() );    

                        // Obtain the number of the client
                        $LastIssuedTicket = mysql_query("SELECT clientNo FROM client ORDER BY clientNo DESC LIMIT 1"); // Query to get last issued ticket

                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($LastIssuedTicket))
                        {

                            $NumberClient = $row['clientNo']; // Pass obtained value to $NumberClient

                        }

                        // Insert client name into the status table with default "Waiting" status
                        $client2 = "INSERT INTO status
                                    VALUES('','Waiting','" . $NumberClient . "','1')"; //for status: 0 meaning waiting, 1 meaning finished

                        $client2Inserted = mysql_query($client2) or die ( mysql_error() );  

                        // Close connection
                        mysql_close($con);

                        echo "
                        <form action='home.html' method = 'post'>

                            <b>Ticket issued successfully!</b><br>
                            <input type='submit' value='Home'>

                        </form>";

                    ?>

                </body>
            </html>
```

server.php

```
            <?php


                // START -------------------------------------------------------
                ini_set('max_execution_time', 200); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
                $socket = stream_socket_server("127.0.0.1:8008", $errno, $errstr);
                if (!$socket) {
                    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
                } else {
                    while($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
                    echo "saljflskajf";
                }
                // -------------------------------------------------------- END
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Please show your code. Otherwise, your question is off-topic.

Comment: ive added what we have so far :)